# Reduce the file size of an converted image

Tags: c#, console, file-conversion

I want to reduce size of an Converted Image for example Image1 not yet converted file size 10MB after conversion the byte output must be 300kb not 10MB byte size below code Conversion of Image with Path to Byte Image Thanks.

```
 static void Upload()
    {
        int count = 0;
        string connstring = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Images;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=testpassword";

        DataTable dtconnection = Query("Select ConnectionString from IT.Connection where isnull(ConnectionString,'')!=''", connstring);
        foreach (DataRow dtcon in dtconnection.Rows)
        {

            DataTable convimage = Query("Select Keyfield,Path from dbo.ConvertedImage where isnull(Path,'')!='' and ISNULL(ConvertedImage,'')='' ", dtcon[0].ToString());

            foreach (DataRow dtrow in convimage.Rows)
            {
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("Converting: " + dtrow[0].ToString() + " , " + count.ToString() + " of " + convimage.Rows.Count);
                Image img = Image.FromFile(@dtrow[1].ToString());
                ImageFormat thisFormat = img.RawFormat;
                string message = string.Format("Converting {0} ", @dtrow[1].ToString());
                byte[] arr;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    img.Save(ms, thisFormat);
                    arr = ms.ToArray();
                }
                string convertedimg = "";
                convertedimg = Convert.ToBase64String(arr);
                Gears.RetriveData2("update dbo.ConvertedImage set ConvertedImage='" + convertedimg + "' where Keyfield = '" + dtrow[0].ToString() + "'", dtcon[0].ToString());
                ClearCurrentConsoleLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Converted: " + dtrow[0].ToString() + " , " + count.ToString() + " of " + convimage.Rows.Count);
            }
        }
        if (count == dtconnection.Rows.Count)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Conversion is Finished. Press enter key to exit.");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Is there any preferences/limits in formats? Are all pictures stored as JPEG/PNG, anything else?

Comment: all image converted to 300kb. yup JPEG and PNG